# How to change MySQL user permission temporarily (Per Connection)

Tags: mysql, permissions, database, connection

I do not know if it is possible at all or not. What I want is that, when a *certain* connection is established, the user not be able to modify data with that connection. This is the scenario:

1. Connection is made
2. user run a query to prevent itself from modifying. something like:

   `mysql->stop grant insert`
3. connection runs its usual queries. but the modifying queries do not run. an error will be thrown.
4. user run a query to reset to initial state:

   `mysql->resume grant insert`

The actual problem that I am facing is that, I have only one user with permission to change data but not able to create another user. But, I also need a *read only* user in certain occasions. Then I thought is it possible to tell `MySQL Server` to temporary deny modify access when the connection is made. But for other connections, the user should have his normal privileges.

Thanks for helping

Comment: How are they connecting to the server? The ideal way to do this depends on what they're using for access.

On to the more important question - why is it that you cannot create another user?

Comment: Thanks @Neil, It's a server restriction. I use this connection in `PHP` scripts to run usual `select,insert,update,delete` queries. Also I use this user for creating tables in `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: You nee to speak to the people who manage your mysql and get them to provide you with a read only user.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that but your MySQL user can only alter privileges if GRANT OPTION is given to that user.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

See also revoke http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html

The syntax would be:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON database.* FROM your user

 grant insert on database.* from your user
```

I don't recommend doing this.

If you need to separate privileges e.g. read/write and read only then you should have two user accounts.